# Can't replace an existing stored procedure that creates a table

Tags: stored-procedures, db2-luw

I have a stored procedure that drops/creates a table. The first time the procedure is created it succeeds and the procedure runs fine.  However, if I try and replace the procedure it gives the error:

```
The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "TABLENAME" of type "TABLE".
```

It does this even though the procedure has a drop statement for "TABLENAME" immediately before the table creation statement.  A stripped down example:

```
create or replace procedure example
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704'
BEGIN END;

drop table TABLENAME;

create table TABLENAME(AN INTEGER);

END;
```

Is there any way to either get DB2 to recognize the drop statement or to ignore the error?

I'm on DB2 v10.1.0.3.

Comment: This looks like a bug (or a "feature"). You could work around it by dynamically executing the `CREATE TABLE` statement: `execute immediate 'create table TABLENAME(AN INTEGER)';`

Answer (score 0):

To run a series of commands as a stand-alone block of SQL, make sure that you use a different SQL delimiter instead of the semi-colon. The semi-colon is used as a statement terminator in SQL PL so you will need to use a different character to delimit multiple commands within your scripts. Change the semi-colon (";") at the end of procedure to something else like "@"

See [SQL Procedural Language (SQL PL)](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7771.sql-procedural-language-sql-pl.aspx)